# How to draw a figure which looks like this

Tags: nodes, edge

[image]

The figure is basically three cycles on 'n' vertices which are adjacent to each other as shown in the figure

Comment: Welcome! What's the problem? How are you trying to draw them? What have you tried?

Answer (score 1):

In my view, I ought not answer this question as it is just a do-it-for-me. However, I'm going to anyway, but please note that all questions (very nearly almost all) should include a Minimal Working (or non-Working) Example which people can use as a basis for testing solutions.

I have no idea what you may or may not know, whether you have any idea which packages you want to use or, even, what a package is. I don't know if you know the meaning of the tags you've chosen or not. Or anything.

Since I can't explain everything, I therefore end up explaining nothing. Here's-An-Image-Do-It-For-Me begets Here's-Some-Code-Figure-It-Out.

```
\documentclass[border=10pt,multi,tikz]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  [
    every node/.append style={inner sep=1.5pt, circle, fill, draw},
  ]
  \foreach \j [count=\k] in {0,30mm,60mm}
    \scoped[xshift=\j]{%
      \draw (-90:1) node (v1) [label=below:$v_{1\k}$] {} \foreach \i in {210,150,...,-30} { -- (\i:1) node {} } ;
    };
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]